# Local Notification on weekly basis on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

How to set notification on weekly basis on button action.

// Notification on weekly basis

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate =  [NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Hello Message";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
}
```

on every week application will notify the message "Hello Message"

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.2:

add:

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = .Weekday
```

Swift 3.0:

```
    let content: UNMutableNotificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "Title"

    content.subtitle = "Subtitle"

    content.body = "Hello Message"

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let alarmTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*7)
    let alarmTimeComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday], from: alarmTime)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: alarmTimeComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: workoutAlarmIdentifier,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    {
        (error) in // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Now is 2:00PM Sat Nov 5
- I have a picker is set to 2:10PM Sat Nov 5
- A local notification will be displayed at 2:10PM Sat Nov 5
- The notification will continue being notified at 2:10PM Sat Nov 12

  ```
      let ok = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "OKIdentifier", title: "Open", options: [.foreground])
      let cancel = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CancelIdentifier", title: "Dismiss", options: [])
      let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "message", actions: [ok, cancel], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.body = "open the SAMPLE app"
      content.categoryIdentifier = "message"

      let alarmTime = datePicker.date
      let alarmTimeComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday], from: alarmTime)
      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: alarmTimeComponent, repeats: true)

      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"five second", content: content, trigger: trigger)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
          if (error != nil){
              //handle here
              print("error : \(error)"  )
          }
      }
  ```